# Sulu wasn't the first homosexual character on Star Trek was he?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

[image]

When Star Trek Beyond revealed Sulu to be gay it made all the news like it was some sort of first occurrence. But weren't there other homosexual characters on Star Trek previously?

Comment: Do you count alternate versions of characters from the [mirror universe](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Mirror_universe), or characters like [trills](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Trill) who could switch from one body to a body of a different sex, causing a previously heterosexual attraction to become homosexual?

Comment: A Trill's not homosexual, is it? I thought they just changed. I seem to remember a TNG episode where they were on a planet that had some type of subtext about it, but I just can't recall.

Comment: "A Trill's not homosexual, is it?" It depends how you define homosexual--that's why I asked. If a trill whose humanoid body is female is attracted to a woman, but the trill's symbiote had previously been in a male humanoid body, would you say that this attraction is homosexual or not?

Comment: Consider that their biological sex has a 50% of changing with each new host, with no apparent experience of gender dysmorphia, I think it's safe to say the joined Trill consciousness is genderfluid.